# Installing scikit-learn with Python3, _superlu.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: dtrsm_

Tags: python3, scikit-learn

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install `scikit-learn` using python 3. An I run into the following error:

```
In [4]: import sklearn
```

produces:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: dtrsm_
```

I installed scikit-learn with:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn
```

And was told:

```
Successfully installed scikit-learn
```

My `python`, `numpy` and `scipy` versions:

```
In [5]: sys.version
Out[5]: '3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'

In [6]: numpy.__version__
Out[6]: '1.10.2'

In [7]: scipy.__version__
Out[7]: '0.16.1'
```

I suspect that I am missing something with blas/atlas libraries, but don't really know how to investigate this issue further.

What additional diagnostics can I do to understand the problem better?

What additional information should I provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace numpy 1.10.2 with 1.10.1 .
Then also reinstall scipy with

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy
```

After that sklearn works fine.

Comment: That certainly helped, I used `sudo pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy`.  I can import `sklearn`. However, I am getting one error when running `scipy.test()`.  `ERROR: test_stats.test_chisquare_masked_arrays`, this probably should not be happening.

Comment: Ah OK, that error does not seem to be a huge deal https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5426